# Why does TextBox ClientRectangle, DisplayRectangle, or Bounds not return displayed size?

Tags: c#, textbox, height, size, width

I'm trying to place a Label within a TextBox. However, I am having some trouble getting the label to position correctly within the text box. I can get it to display within the textbox, but that's where my issue arises. When I try and position the label, it doesn't appear to work correctly. I have the following snippet to add the Label within the constructor of the TextBox:

```
        Label lblClear = new Label();
        lblClear.Text = "X";
        lblClear.Font = this.Font;
        lblClear.Location = new Point(this.DisplayRectangle.X + (this.DisplayRectangle.Width - 15), this.Bounds.Y);
        lblClear.Size = new Size(15, 15);

        this.Controls.Add(lblClear);
```

However, this does not put it all the way to the right of the textbox as I am expecting, but rather somewhere in the middle of the textbox. Why doesn't ClientRectangle, DisplayRectangle, or Bound return the size of the textbox as I'm thinking it should? Is the underlying texbox rectangle actually smaller than what is displayed on screen?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of what I am talking about:

[image]

And here is the class I have:

```
public class SearchTextBox : TextBox
{
    public SearchTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Label lblClear = new Label();
        lblClear.Text = "X";
        lblClear.Font = this.Font;
        lblClear.Location = new Point(this.DisplayRectangle.X + (this.DisplayRectangle.Width - 15), this.Bounds.Y);
        lblClear.Size = new Size(15, 15);

        this.Controls.Add(lblClear);
    }
}
```

Edit: I got it working, but this only took affect when I removed the textbox from my form and re-added it...

Comment: "I'm not looking for this to resize."  That looks **wider** than a standard TextBox dropped on the form.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show a picture of how it isn't working?

**If you want that "X" to STAY at the right side when the TextBox is resized then you would need to Anchor() it to the Right side.**

Here is what I get with the code:

[image: TextBox with 'X']

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{

    public MyTextBox()
    {
        Label lblClear = new Label();
        lblClear.Text = "X";
        lblClear.Font = this.Font;
        lblClear.Location = new Point(this.DisplayRectangle.X + (this.DisplayRectangle.Width - 15), this.Bounds.Y);
        lblClear.Size = new Size(15, 15);

        this.Controls.Add(lblClear);
    }

}
```

Comment: I Edited my original post to include a picture and the class that I have. I'm not looking for this to resize. It will be a fixed width textbox, but I can't seem to get the label to move all the way right even though my constructor code looks to be about the same as yours.